# How can i fill gap between navbar and div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]Here i'm new to Bootstrap please help me how can i remove gap between navbar and div

```
 [![<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img alt="Brand" src="/show/100-flat-icons-by-graphicloads/home-icon.html">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="side_Bar">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <ul>
                <li>Swiggy</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>][1]][1]
```

Comment: It will be good if you can make a fiddle or code snippet

Comment: Which boostrap version are you using??

Comment: @Firday bootstrap3.3

Comment: Please show some demo or screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Santosh please go to my pic

Comment: @JpDuminy Answer by bhavik should work. Did you try ?

Comment: Try adding this .navbar { padding:0} to your css   if it works let me know..

Comment: @Santosh anf friday thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   .navbar.mb-0 {
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default mb-0">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="navbar-header">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img alt="Brand" src="/show/100-flat-icons-by-graphicloads/home-icon.html">
                    </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="side_Bar">
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                <ul>
                    <li>Swiggy</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```